# Remove HTML tags in IQueryable Linq query result in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm having following Linq query

```
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {

               var query = from product in db.AB_Product
                    join productvsfield in db.AB_Product_vs_Field on product.ProductID equals productvsfield.Product_ID
                    join type in db.AB_ProductType on product.ProductTypeID equals type.ProductTypeID
                    where productvsfield.Field_ID == "F000001"
                    select new DashboardViewModel

                    {
                         Product_ID = product.ProductID,
                         Product_Title_EN = productvsfield.Field_Value_EN,
                         Product_Title_AR = productvsfield.Field_Value_AR,
                         Product_Type_EN = type.ProductTypeNameEn,                             
                         Product_Type_AR = type.ProductTypeNameAr,
                         ModifiedDate = product.UpdatedDate,
                    };

        return View(query);

    }
```

for that query I'm getting view like below

[image]

since Its contains some HTML tags, I used to change my code to like below

```
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {

               var query = from product in db.AB_Product
                    join productvsfield in db.AB_Product_vs_Field on product.ProductID equals productvsfield.Product_ID
                    join type in db.AB_ProductType on product.ProductTypeID equals type.ProductTypeID
                    where productvsfield.Field_ID == "F000001"
                    select new DashboardViewModel

                    {
                         Product_ID = product.ProductID,
                         Product_Title_EN = productvsfield.Field_Value_EN,
                         Product_Title_AR = productvsfield.Field_Value_AR,
                         Product_Type_EN = type.ProductTypeNameEn,                             
                         Product_Type_AR = type.ProductTypeNameAr,
                         ModifiedDate = product.UpdatedDate,
                    };

        var filtered = Regex.Replace(query, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim();

        return View(filtered);

    }
```

using regex I try to do this.but then I'm getting unexpected view like this

[image]

Comment: `query` is not a *string*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that you applying Replace on query object, but you need do replace on fields where you have HTML e.g.:

```
var result = (from product in db.AB_Product
    join productvsfield in db.AB_Product_vs_Field on product.ProductID equals productvsfield.Product_ID
    join type in db.AB_ProductType on product.ProductTypeID equals type.ProductTypeID
    where productvsfield.Field_ID == "F000001"
    select new DashboardViewModel

    {
         Product_ID = product.ProductID,
         Product_Title_EN = productvsfield.Field_Value_EN,
         Product_Title_AR = productvsfield.Field_Value_AR,
         Product_Type_EN = type.ProductTypeNameEn,                             
         Product_Type_AR = type.ProductTypeNameAr,
         ModifiedDate = product.UpdatedDate,
    }).ToList();


result = result.Select(x => new DashboardViewModel
    {
         Product_ID = x.ProductID,
         Product_Title_EN = Regex.Replace(x.Product_Title_EN, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim(),
         Product_Title_AR = Regex.Replace(x.Product_Title_AR, @"<[^>]+>|&nbsp;", "").Trim(),
         Product_Type_EN = x.Product_Type_EN,                             
         Product_Type_AR = x.Product_Type_AR,
         ModifiedDate = x.ModifiedDate,
    }).ToList()

return View(result);
```

Comment: getting this error `'DashboardViewModel' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'DashboardViewModel'`

Comment: @kez I updated my answer - there was brackets `()` missing around main query.